# ng-repeat and unique functions for each row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I'm working on building a timesheet application. On the create timesheet page, the user is able to charge hours worked against different tasks. These tasks are tied back to projects, so the workflow is:

1) User selects project.

2) API fires and populates my select list with the tasks associated with that project.

3) User picks a task, and charges their time to that task.

Each row is on the timesheet is generated with ng-repeat triggered by a button the page.

My issue is that in my projectIDSelected function, I'm pushing the tasks to $scope.tasks. If the user tries to charge time to a different project, the tasks are overwritten and as a result the first row in the timesheet has it's tasks change to whatever is returned in the 2nd row.

I'm not sure how to use ng-repeat to handle adding the timesheet rows, but have a 'unique' repository for each timesheet row in $scope.

My code is the following:

Controller function:

```
this.projectIDSelected = function (data) {

    console.log("project id selected function has fired.");
    console.log($scope.projects);

    TaskApi.GetProjectTasks(
        {
            params: {
                projectId: data,
            }
        },
        //handle success
        function (res) {
            console.log("Tasks for ProjectId retrived");
            console.log(res);
            var json = {};
            $scope.tasks = [];
            for (i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                json = res.data[i];
                json.text = json.taskName;
                delete json.taskName;
                $scope.tasks.push(json);
            }

            // $scope.tasks = res.data;

        },
        //handle failure
        function (res) {
            console.log(res);

        }
    )
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight" ng-controller="createTimesheetCtrl as createTSCtrl" >

<tr ng-repeat="taskDetail in taskDetails | filter:createTSCtrl.filterTaskDetail" class="footable-even">
```

```
<!-- editable Project (select-local) -->
<span editable-select="taskDetail.project" e-form="tableform" e-ng-model="projectID" e-ng-change ="createTSCtrl.projectIDSelected($data)" e-ng-options="pj.id as pj.text for pj in projects">
{{ createTSCtrl.showProject(taskDetail) }}
</span>
 </td>
```

Comment: in the ng-repeat you are looking for a taskDetails, that should be in a $scope.taskDetails variable in the js controller. I can't see any. Maybe you meant ng-repeat="task in tasks"

Comment: Task details is an array in $scope. Each entry in that array corresponds to 1 row on the timesheet page. So when the user 'adds' another task they want to charge time to, the button on the page that does that is just appending another row to this array. On init $scope.taskDetails is populated with 1 blank row in that array. My controller is actually pretty big so I'm trying to just post the relevant bits of it, sorry about the confusion.